# How to animate Laplace operator $ e^{-st} \ s =(\sigma+j \omega)$ which is a spiral

Tags: animation

like this

[image: $e^{-st}]

It goes around origin with a dereasing  radius starting from a point on the XY-plane and goes up parallel with the Z-axis positive direction at the same time. It is driven by the time `t` as a parametric in $ e^{-st} ,\ s =(\sigma+j \omega)$ which gives its motion equation. ($\sigma>0$ $\omega>0$, $s$ is a complex number)

I have read [How to draw a phasor animation with Mathematica?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/211291/how-to-draw-a-phasor-animation-with-mathematica), however, I am new to Mathematica
Dynamic Interactivity as a Matlab user, I still not get used to Mathematica due to its function style.

Comment: Can you add some background info? What are you trying to animate? By *Laplace operator* what are you refering to? It's not [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace_operator), right?

Comment: Well, you have to type at least your starting equations in MA style. In this form your question will likely be closed.

Comment: @yarchik I accidentally found the source of the picture: https://zhuanlan.zhihu.com/p/40783304

Comment: @xzczd yes, from there. However, I could not upload the dynamic gif.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have no idea if my functions are "correct", I'm just eyeballing the image and assuming how it should be animated.

```
ClearAll[func]
func[t_]:={E^-t Cos[20t],E^-t Sin[20t]}
Animate[Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[Append[func@t,t],{t,0,u},
      PlotStyle->Black],
    ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[t func@#,#]&/@
      Range[0,u,.01]],{t,0,1},PlotStyle->Red],
    AxesLabel->{"sin(-\[Omega]t)","cos(-\[Omega]t)","t"},
    PlotLabel->"\[Omega]=1rad/s Not Made by J Pan; Made by Adam"
],{u,0,2}]
```

The first `ParametricPlot` does the black spiral from `0` to `u` and the second plots many lines sampled from `0` to `u`.  Mathematica automatically chooses tight (and changing) `PlotRange`s for the bounding boxes; we can force it to be the largest it will ever be:

```
ClearAll[func,plot]
func[t_]:={E^-t Cos[20t],E^-t Sin[20t]}
plot[u_,opts_:{}]:=Show[
    ParametricPlot3D[Append[func@t,t],{t,0,u},
      PlotStyle->Black],
    ParametricPlot3D[Evaluate[Append[t func@#,#]&/@
      Range[0,u,.01]],{t,0,1},PlotStyle->Red],
    AxesLabel->{"sin(-\[Omega]t)","cos(-\[Omega]t)","t"},
    PlotLabel->"\[Omega]=1rad/s Not Made by J Pan; Made by Adam",
Sequence@@opts]
```

Then the animation becomes

```
Animate[plot[u,AbsoluteOptions[plot@2,PlotRange]],{u,0,2}]
```

[image: gif]

Clearly I have messed up the `AxesLabel`s.

To address and add on to the comments: in my opinion it doesn't take much to improve questions like this dramatically.  Some hand drawn (with ms paint or other) arrows indicating what should be animated and how would make the question more clear.  Explicit parameterizations for the curves could help too.  MMA code that just did a static plot would be epic.

`Animate` is of course not the function I used to produce that gif; animate is in general slow.  To render all the frames at once and assemble the gif, I used something like

```
Export["filename.gif",Join@@{#,Reverse@#}&@Rest@Table[
  plot[u,AbsoluteOptions[plot@2,PlotRange]],
  {u,0,2,.1}],AnimationRepetitions->\[Infinity]]
```

and I also played with `"DisplayDurations"`, the number of frames (i.e. changing the value `.1`), and `"ColorMapLength"` for file size reduction.

Comment: That is exactly what I want.

Comment: On my machine, it runs not fluently .

Comment: It's a computationally expensive way to make this animation -- realistically, only little segment increments should be re-rendered.  Alas, it's probably still the best way to do it.  I've included the code for the gif so that the animation may be played without stuttering once exported.